# Show duplicates values in Left outer join once

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

There are plenty questions on SO regarding how to remove the duplicate records in the left outer join. I have a simple left outer join like this between two tables Table1 and Table2 where Table1 has one to many relationship with Table2 (I have directly written this simple query here just to explain what I am after and it is not the actual query),

```
SELECT a.ID, a.Name, b.Value
FROM Table1 a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 b ON a.ID == b.Table1_ID
```

Now this returns the result like this,

```
ID    Name     Value
1     Test1    TestValue1
1     Test1    TestValue2
1     Test1    TestValue3
1     Test1    NULL
2     Test2    TestValue4
2     Test2    NULL
2     Test2    TestValue5
```

Now this output is correct and I understand that it is a correct behavior. But is there some way by which I can get the following output. This might be simple but I have not done this before and everytime I search for the solution I came across the question and threads asking to remove the duplicates. I don't want to remove the duplicates. Just want to show the values from Table1 just once like below,

```
ID    Name     Value
1     Test1    TestValue1
               TestValue2
               TestValue3
               NULL
2     Test2    TestValue4
               NULL
               TestValue5
```

Comment: This should be done in the application side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` to determine the first row among related values:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT 
        a.ID, 
        a.Name, 
        b.Value,
        Rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.ID ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM Table1 a 
    LEFT JOIN Table2 b 
        ON a.ID = b.Table1_ID
)
SELECT
    ID  = CASE WHEN Rn = 1 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), a.ID) ELSE '' END),
    Name = CASE WHEN Rn = 1 THEN Name ELSE '' END),
    Value
FROM CTE
```

Replace `ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))` with the column you want the `ROW_NUMBER` to be based from.

Comment: I understand that it is easier in the application side then in the database but it is some unique requirements where data has to be presented to someone directly from database. Thank you for your kind help.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, this type of data processing would be done in the application layer.  You *can* do it in the database, but it is not a good idea.  SQL result sets are unordered, unless you explicitly have an `order by`.

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN id END) as id,
       (CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN name END) as name,
       value
FROM (SELECT a.ID, a.Name, b.Value,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.id, a.name ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as as seqnum
      FROM Table1 a LEFT OUTER JOIN
           Table2 b
           ON a.ID = b.Table1_ID
     )
ORDER BY id, name, seqnum;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.